# What are the precedents for the game elements of "Squid Game" beyond "Battle Royale"?

Tags: cinema-history, squid-game, battle-royale

Having watched [*Squid Game* (2021 - )](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10919420/), I have the feeling that, while it is very different from [*Battle Royale* (2000)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0266308/), there are a number of elements that the two works have in common, in the way that the game is depicted:

- people are gassed into artificial sleep and kidnapped to a deserted island;
- the game is extremely lethal - there is expected to be exactly a single survivor;
- the players die either when eliminated by game rules, or at the hand of one another (importantly, there is not a "hunter" type of player who are supposed to kill the non-hunter players);
- the game takes place in the contemporary world;
- the PA system regularly plays Classical European Music;

Does *Battle Royale* establish an archetype of such "absolute lethality games in the modern world"? Or can most of the listed elements be found in previous works of cinema/TV?

Comment: Another similar film: [As the Gods Will](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/As_the_Gods_Will_(film)) (2014)

Comment: @galacticninja zero bravest money game, akagi, kaiji, liar game, one outs, kakegurui, umineko/higurashi, eden of the east/higashi no eden, mirai nikki/future diary, platinum end, king's game, danganronpa?

Comment: I feel this will be closed as "opinion based", but *The Prisoner* and Stephen King's *The Long Walk* come to mind, but I'm sure there are plenty of "deadly game" works before this, right back to Roman gladiators and perhaps even further back...

Comment: One or two of these?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_about_death_games

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squid_Game) of Squid Game, it seems very apparent that Hwang Dong-hyuk, the screenwriter and developer of the series, was very derivative in many aspects of the series.  He used the actual names of childhood friends (for not just one, but *several* of the main characters), and he admittedly was influenced by Battle Royale, Liar Game and other Japanese survival manga.  It's very probable that he took the idea of playing music over a loud speaker directly from Battle Royale, and the rest from other survival manga sources.